# Docker Alpine Linux python (missing)

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I have a pipeline which deploys my container from GitLab. Last deployment was 5 days ago and went without any problems. Today I deploy it and get the following error:

```
$ apk add --no-cache curl python py-pip
 fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
 fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.12/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
 ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
   python (missing):
     required by: world[python]
```

My job definition is:

```
my-deploy:
  type: my-deploy
  image: docker:stable
  script:
    - apk update
    - apk add --no-cache curl python py-pip <-- Here the erorr happens
    ...
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

From [this](https://github.com/docker-library/docker/issues/240) issue on the Docker's repo:

> This was "broken" while updating our base from `alpine:3.11` to `alpine:3.12`.

In order to fix it you need to specify the version of Python directly, e.g.:

```
apk add python2
// or
apk add python3
```

Comment: I am using docker windows desktop application. I received this error on getting-started repo. Come on! getting-started has issue? I updated the DockerFile `RUN apk add --no-cache python g++ make` with `RUN apk add --no-cache python3 g++ make`. This fixed the issue. Thanks.

Comment: I was able to install python2 on `ruby:2.7.6-alpine3.14` but not `ruby:2.7.6-alpine3.15`

Answer (score 73):

Try this command:

```
apk add --update --no-cache curl py-pip
```

It will install `python3` automatically with pip.

My understanding is that Python 2 has been decommissioned from the latest Alpine packages.

Comment: [Sunsetting Python 2](https://www.python.org/doc/sunset-python-2/)

Comment: i dont think we need curl here

Comment: `curl` was in the question, so I think he included it to match that

Comment: Thanks, python2 was no longer working for me but with py-pip it worked fine.

Answer (score 20):

For future readers:

I got a similar error with `node:14-alpine`

```
ERROR: unable to select packages:  
  python2 (no such package):  
    required by: world[python2]
```

But I couldn't use the other answers listed in this question because I needed exactly `python2` and running `apk add python2` was giving me the error above.

After a while I realized that in the latest alpine version, there's only `python3` ([there's no python2](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=python2&branch=edge)).

So the solution was to use an older version of alpine that have `python2` ([alpine v3.15](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=python2&branch=v3.15)).

So the fix was changing `node:14-alpine` to `node:14-alpine3.15`

I know this isn't the exact same error, but while trying to find an answer for my error, I always ended up here, so I'm leaving this for future readers that might have the same problem.

Comment: I m getting the same error in the pipelne. I m using `image: node:16.15-alpine` . But based on the Alpine page that you posted above, if i use `node:16.15-alpine:3.15` is it going to pass ?

Comment: I kept the same nodejs image, i mention above,  and i upgraded to `python3`.  This is the affected line: `apk --update add make g++ npm autoconf zlib-dev automake file nasm python3 git py-pipq`

Comment: Only this worked for me. After 3 days of solving same sh*t. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I've fix following this
https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/issues/11605

Updating your code to install python3:

```
before_script:
- apk add --update --no-cache curl jq py3-configobj py3-pip py3-setuptools python3 python3-dev
```

Answer (score 3):

What solved it for me is [this solution](https://github.com/gliderlabs/docker-alpine/issues/386#issuecomment-380096034) posted on GitHub.

```
RUN echo -e "http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/main\nhttp://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.5/community" > /etc/apk/repositories
```